# Carregar informações do firestore flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Alguém sabe me dizer onde estou errado nesse código?

```
import 'package:anime_app/models/home_page.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AnimeList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: Firestore.instance.collection('animes').snapshots(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text('Carregando...');

            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                DocumentSnapshot doc = snapshot.data.documents[index];

                return ListView(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      width: 100,
                      height: 100,
                      color: Colors.black,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        image: DecorationImage(
                            image: NetworkImage(doc['link_img'])),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              },
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: (Leia em tom descontraído) Acho que você errou é na pergunta... O que está ou não acontecendo? Qual o resultado esperado? Da algum erro? xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seja bem-vindo!

Meu caro, primeiramente, garanta que seu código retorna todos os elementos da coleção que você deseja. Depois disso você injeta os elementos na sua lista. Existe muito problema de "permissão" de leitura dos dados, que você pode facilmente detectar com um código simples:

```
void _onPressed() {
  firestoreInstance.collection("orders").get().then((querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.docs.forEach((result) {
      print(result.data());
    });
  });
}
```

Depois recomendo você dar uma olhada neste componente:

[Cloud Firestore Plugin for Flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore#-example-tab-)